# Why does the implementation_imports linting rule only work in lib directory?

Tags: dart, lint

I'm pretty new to dart and as far as I understand you should never import from the `lib/src` directory of other packages, as it is (by convention) implementation code of the respective package. This should be checked by the `implementation_imports` linting rule.

So I added the rule to my `analysis_options.yaml` file:

```
linter:
  rules:
    - implementation_imports
```

and this works fine for files in the `lib/` directory, I can see the message in the VS code Problems section as well as when running `dart analyze`. However it seems as though files in other top level directories such as `bin/` and `test/` are ignored.

I tried searching for this issue but haven't found anything useful or related.
Is this by design? Is there something wrong with my configuration/version?
Because I don't understand why this rule shouldn't apply to directories other than lib?

`Dart SDK version: 3.2.6`

```
dev_dependencies:
  lints: ^3.0.0
```

**Edit:**

[reported as a bug on github](https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/4859)

Comment: To be clear, you're asking why `dart analyze` doesn't report warnings if files in `bin/` or in `test/` have things like `import 'package:foo/src/something.dart';`, right?  It's probably a bug.  [Report it](https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/new/choose).

Comment: @jamesdlin yes exactly. I wasn't sure if it was an error in my setup because I had some trouble getting the linter to work. Then I realised it just doesn't check the rule and I don't understand why it wouldn't be important in other directories.

Answer (score 0):

In the [source code](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/pkg/linter/lib/src/rules/implementation_imports.dart) of this linter rule, it has these lines:

```dart
@override
void visitImportDirective(ImportDirective node) {
  var importUri = node.element?.importedLibrary?.source.uri;
  var sourceUri = node.element?.source.uri;

  // Test for 'package:*/src/'.
  if (!isImplementation(importUri)) {
    return;
  }

  // If the source URI is not a `package` URI bail out.
  if (!isPackage(sourceUri)) {
    return;
  }

  if (!samePackage(importUri, sourceUri)) {
    rule.reportLint(node.uri);
  }
}
```

Notice how it's checking if the `sourceUri` is a package, and "bail out" when it's not. This is the implementation of `isPackage` function:

```dart
bool isPackage(Uri? uri) => uri?.scheme == 'package';
```

When the source file is not in the `/lib` directory, it won't have the `package` scheme in its URI (`package:` is only for the `/lib` directory, see [this](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-packages#importing-library-files) and [this](https://dart.dev/language/libraries#using-libraries)). It makes this `visitImportDirective` function returns in that check and won't have that `reportLint` method called.

Comment: This doesn't explain the rationale for *why* the analyzer doesn't warn if files in non-`lib` directories import `package:.../src/...`.  I suspect that there is no rationale and that it's just a bug.

Comment: @jamesdlin It doesn't look like a bug to me, as the author left this comment "If the source URI is not a `package` URI bail out" as if it was intentional. The `isPackage` function and this comment is not found anywhere else in the linter package. But I agree that this answer still has not pointed out yet what the rationale is.

Comment: The comment is mostly useless and describes what the code is doing but not why.  The check could be there purely because `samePackage` probably expects two `package:` URI arguments, and the author of the code did not consider that files in `bin/` and `test/` would fail the `isPackage` check.

Comment: @jamesdlin You're right, it's probably worth a bug report. Until we get there, it's more likely to be opinion-based. My answer is more on the facts side.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan thanks for clearing up that this is indeed the implemented behaviour though jamesdlin is right it doesn't answer the why. I'll report it as a bug.